# Using Automation, is it bannable?

Tags: steam-monster-game

The latest steam summer sale game is just a glorified "cookie-clicker" game. As such I've seen users post about being able to automate the clicks and effectively cheat in the game, does anyone know if users who do this will be banned?

Comment: Given how little difference this will make, you're only 1 of 1000 players, probably not.

Comment: I've tested it and the best I can do is 50 click per second. I figure even a super fast person would be lucky to get 10, so with a simple program you have the impact that 5-10 other people would. If everyone or a majority used it, it would certainly cause a large discrepancy. But seeing as how there aren't any rewards for killing things faster, (or there don't seem to be) there's really no purpose to this other than to cheat for the sake of cheating. After testing it myself, I didn't notice anything strange on my account, so probably not is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valve works in strange ways when it comes to bans, so I can't authoritatively say if you will or won't be banned for "cheating" at the game.  They've taken a hard stance at times, but ignored other flagrant, profitable cheating avenues in the past.

That said, there is absolutely no reason to cheat - there are already built-in ways to automatically do damage, and there's doesn't appear to be anything tangible as a reward for doing more clicks yourself.

If we balance the risk (unknown) against the reward (nonexistent) it seems pointless to take the chance.

Comment: I can't help but laugh at "no reason to cheat". With an autoclicker you'd get easily 20-30 clicks/second and since the damage of both trees is similar that's a lot more damage. And that's not considering the whole raining gold thingy that will make most of your income.

Comment: @meneldal I suppose we can agree to disagree - I just started today's game, haven't clicked once, and we're gaining around 1,000 levels every 5 minutes.  Raining Gold doesn't make any kind of dent in my gold reserves.  I don't really see the need to click.

Comment: @agent86 Multiple Raining Gold power-ups on a boss produces an absurdly high amount of gold (~+52,000 per click per active raining gold), far more than you can gain through idling and collecting gold drops. Stacking them together as a team is the fastest way to gain gold, and the faster you can click, the more gold you can get.  In fact, it's part of the winning strategy. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223694/55285

Comment: @Zibbobz Gold isn't the winning strategy, neither is clicking. The Wormhole and Like New items are what get you to absurdly high levels. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224150/

Comment: "no reason to cheat", the maximum badge is level 100,000,000. The only practical way to get this is using WH strategy (as mentioned above) for _many_ hours. In other words, Valve knows about the bots and has made the maximum reward only practically obtainable this way.

Comment: The WH thing only works if the team is coordinated which doesn't happen in random games. In this case, raining gold is the only thing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Valve doesn't care if player cheat like this. People from Reddit have been using scripts to play the game in order to achieve seemingly impossible levels. Their scripts managed get them what is apparently the highest level possible in the game, level 100,000,000. Instead of banning them, [Valve rewarded them with a new badge](http://www.reddit.com/r/SteamMonsterGame/comments/3adcae/the_new_badge_for_100m_is_a_wormhole/):

[image: Level 100,000,000 Monster Summer Badge]