# What's the best strategy for the Steam Monster Game?

Tags: steam-monster-game

Guides like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b36R5CqBI_I) barely scratch the surface. How does one survive the [Monster Game](http://steamcommunity.com/minigame/towerattack/) and best help one's team? Surely not all wasted potential I see is trolling.

Comment: I cleaned up some of the comments - I appreciate the OP is curious as to what is going on here, but at this point, the comments aren't helpful. Unless someone decides to comment and explain their own personal reasoning, it's best just to accept that sometimes, downvotes happen, and as much as it would be nice to get a clear indication as to why, it's not going to happen in every case, because of how the system is designed (and before you ask, no, that's not likely to change any time soon.)

Comment: The answers below are solid in general, however, I think this answer can be customized to the way you play the game.  If you login every few hours (like described in the vid) vs sitting there for a solid couple hours just playing it, IMO the answer differs.

Comment: @joedragons What's your DPS and how long can you keep it up without cheating?

Comment: *hint hint* use [script 1](https://github.com/wchill/steamSummerMinigame/raw/master/autoPlay.user.js) and [script 2](https://github.com/DannyDaemonic/SteamMonsterAutoUpgradeManager/raw/master/upgrademanager-noelemental.user.js) with [tampermonkey for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)/[greasemonkey for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) *hint hint*

Comment: @ardaozkal Legit by [this Valve employee's badge](http://steamcommunity.com/id/drunkenf00l/badges/23).

Comment: @ardaozkal of course, if you are using script 1, all these strategies are wrong, as doing damage to the bosses is bad.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Lol, mine is better at [8m](http://steamcommunity.com/id/ardaozkal/badges/23). Missed [12m](http://steamcommunity.com/id/silverhustle/badges/23) train though. However, I'm still on idling, I might go up more.

Comment: @Kexlox updated, now doesn't hit bosses. (as of version 4.7.2)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman just woke up and I'm in level 52m! Wow!

Comment: Pressing F5 until you get a card dropped.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. **Don't die.** Expect to take about 300k damage on level 569. Energy Shields grant 100k health each, and are unlocked after 10 Light Armor and 10 Heavy Armor.
2. **Keep your team alive.** Use your Medics ability every 5 minutes if the middle health bars are up and there is no active healing. The leftmost health bar is shared with the number of dead players, who can be resurrected with the Resurrection item. Items are obtained via boss drops or bought at the start of the game using badge points (BP) from previous games (1 BP per 10 levels). These are normal monsters: [image: Normal monsters]
3. **Click for gold** to upgrade Shields and Farming Equipment (*deals 1000 DPS even while Steam is closed*). Between boss levels, use abilities to deal extra damage and *take out the spawners first* before they spawn more low-gold, time-wasting minions. Note that Tactical Nuke etc. target the last monster you've clicked.
4. **Use the Raining Gold items on bosses.** ***Not damage items.*** Raining Gold immediately copies 1% of the loot *per click*. As
   bosses have a lot of hitpoints, you can easily get all clickers *multiple times the base loot, millions!* To compare, level 549 Spawners give only 1730 gold per click. Bosses take up the entire screen and appear in a random lane on each level multiple of 10. This is a boss: [image: Boss monster]
5. **Multiply your damage** via Elemental Damage and tier upgrades (*a Railgun does 1000 damage per click*). Mouseover the buttons to compare DPS increase and cost. As lane elements are random per level, and bonus increments are fixed, spread out your elemental levels.
6. **Switch lanes.** Help out other lanes and take advantage of their active abilities. The log shows events in all three lanes.
7. **Check back** to spend collected items and use your cooled-down abilities. Games reset every day at 16:00 [UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html), so spend your items before that. Raining Gold works better at higher levels, so *don't* spend them all early or when a boss is about to die.
8. **Buy smart.** The defense, auto, and click upgrades currently have five tiers each. Each tier is ten times as good as the one before it and starts out cheap, so only buy an upgrade if it costs less than a tenth of what the next tier does. Remember that you'll probably be AFK most of the time, so defense and auto are best. Morale Boost unlocks at Auto-fire Cannon level 20.
9. **Play again.** Only buy *Raining Gold* (10 BP each) as that
   has the most lasting effect by allowing everyone to prepare for
   higher levels. Metal Detector is worthless as it needs to be active when a monster dies and earns less than Raining Gold.
   Remaining BP can be spent on early game items Treasure (2 BP) to help you upgrade and Pumped Up (1 BP) for a little health boost.
   **Note:** [Like lunboks said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224150/23597), if you plan to stick around for a level multiple of 100, buy some [Wormholes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463162075/) and use them there to skip the next 10 levels each and give every player 500k gold. With nukers and no cooldown boosts, you'll only be able to use a few wormholes, though:  [image: Warphole on 100s to skip 10 levels]

Your [Monster Summer Badge](http://steamcommunity.com/id/drunkenf00l/badges/23) will track the level of the last boss you helped defeat. Cheating even gives you an [easter egg at level 100,000,000.](http://steamed.kotaku.com/valve-sees-players-game-the-steam-summer-sale-rewards-1712664145)

Comment: There is **Personal Training** (granting 1M health) after  **Energy Shields** and **AFK Equipment** (dealing 10K DPS) after **Farming Equipment**. I think they are a novelty of today. [More info on this reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/39i0qc/psa_how_the_monster_game_works_an_indepth).

Comment: @Reyssor When did those get added?  They weren't there the last day I was actually playing the game instead of idleing... which was only two days ago.

Comment: @Powerlord During the reset of the game servers. The resets happen everyday about 1 hour before the daily update of the sales themselves. The last one similarly added yet another level to the upgrades (see the previous reddit link, it seems to be be up to date). 16:00 GMT for the game reset and 17:00 GMT for the sales update if I'm not mistaken in the time conversion.

Comment: You should use **Detect Metal** / **Treasure** at bosses too, cos it gives more gold per click while **Raining Gold** is active.

Comment: @NabilA. Metal Detector only increases loot on death, and is not as good as Raining Gold.

Comment: **Detect Metal** increases the gold value of the boss and each **Raining Gold** gives 1% of mob value on click. Or am I worng?

Comment: @NabilA. **Metal Detector** temporarily increases the loot that's dropped when a monster dies and does not affect Raining Gold (short of more people trying to kill the monster instead of bleeding it). Raining Gold is only based on the monster's base loot, and not affected by Metal Detector.

Comment: There is a lot of talk about elements, and that each game has two elements which are most beneficial for you to upgrade, the other two are not. They are saying that it is better to max out one or two elements rather than all of them.

Comment: @rlb.usa That's when you autoselect your element lane and/or keep getting Max Elemental Damage items.

Comment: +1 for `do not use damage items on bosses`. This ruins the extremely potent **Raining Gold** + boss click combo.

Comment: @sorbet Thanks, but i now have tier 7 armor and auto on level 20+k (all night), and manually beating bosses is getting annoying. Using Boss Loot just isn't as fun as spamming Wormhole on every 100th level.

Answer (score 13):

The overall best strategy that all the [top rooms](https://lab.xpaw.me/towerattack.php) use is simple, but it requires a very high degree of coordination, so unless you join an organized "pre-made" room, it will probably not be very effective.

1. At the start of the round, use all your badge points to buy two items ("Wormhole" and "Like New") in about a 5:1 ratio
2. On boss levels divisible by 100, **stop doing damage entirely** and just spam these items
3. Do not upgrade your auto-damage further than 10 Auto-fire Cannons (which unlocks the Boss Loot upgrade)

---

Wormholes skip a level when the current level is cleared, but if used on a level divisible by 100, they skip *10 levels* instead. "Like New" clears all cooldowns in the lane, which can be used repeatedly to quickly dump more Wormholes.

By stalling these levels, you can queue up extremely large level skips to the tune of **millions of levels**, provided your room has enough Wormholes.

That's it. Upgrade-wise, your #1 priority should be health, because you can quickly get into levels where the monsters will one-shot you with millions of HP. Click damage and elemental upgrades are not important.

Comment: This is the ***only*** way to get to maximum level. The maximum level is 100,000,000. It's impossible to finish the game using DPS. The only practical way to accomplish this strategy and group coordination is by using scripts. There are two bot scripts ([wchill's](https://github.com/wchill/steamSummerMinigame) and [YOWH](https://github.com/YeOldeWH/MonsterMinigameWormholeWarp)). I think the largest level jump was 9 million yesterday. [This website](http://drx.pl/steamgame/) has some nice visualisations of group growth.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was in a room that hit 96M. We were unable to hit 100M because of people Nuking the boss on levels divisible by 100. you do more harm than good when people are using wormholes. And as Annan stated, you can use a script to automate the wormhole use if you so choose, but, just dont attack the boss, don't even look at it, go to a different lane.

Answer (score 9):

### The Easy Strategy

I've been playing this game each day since the sale started, and I can safely say this is the best strategy:

**Start a new game as soon as possible after 9am Pacific.**

With this strategy, I've been to the highest levels I've ever been, exponentially higher than when I start a game later in the day.

For reference, in my current game, which I started around 9:10 am yesterday, **I'm level 17,250 having clicked a grand total of 0 times.**  I have 50 or so of every consumable item, and have more money than I know what to do with.  We clear levels so fast the spawners don't have time to show up on the screen before they're dead.  Against bosses, we deal damage in the hundreds of quintillions.

The previous day I started around 11am Pacific and got to around level 250.  I expect to shatter my record by a wide margin every day I manage to get a game started around 9am Pacific.

I suspect this works because the truly "hardcore" players start new games early, so I end up with a lot of people who have a lot of badge points and who have been at high levels in the past.  (Like myself!)  Having a lot of previously high-level players in your lobby means you can move very fast at first.

### Stuff You Can Do Anyhow

Beyond that point, it matters a lot less what you do.  My suggestion is to invest heavily into the "Light Armor" and "Auto-Fire Cannon" trees, as this will keep you alive longer and have you dealing more damage without having to invest much effort.  I just get each skill to level 10 and then ignore that tier in favor of the next one.

Ideally here, you'd balance it so that you're only paying for the higher tier when it costs less than 10x the previous one, but again, way too much money for me to care.  The first few ranks in any new tier of these skills are so cheap that it makes it very worth unlocking them.

Invest in elemental damage - ideally everyone would specialize so that "Max Elemental Damage" consumable has the most effect.  I tend to peanut-butter it across because the team damage is so high it doesn't really matter.

There are a couple of abilities that have minimum requirements in the "Armor Piercing Round" tree, so I will grab ranks down there until I can get the Tactical Nuke and so forth.

With badge points, I used to stock up on Treasure items, as they help in the early game.  Having a good dozen or so of these is helpful, for sure, but past that point it becomes annoying to use them up, not to mention the number you'll find from beating bosses.  Past a few of each item, I tend to blow my badge points on expensive items just to use them up.

If you've got an insane amount of badge points, you might as well stock up on Wormholes - they can be used to very rapidly level up the whole game.  I've got people in today's game who are using them so that every level we clear skips a good 5-10 levels easily.  This might be suicidal if done too much in a low-level game, since the payout in return for level skipping is somewhat low.  In a "power leveling" game started around 9am Pacific, it's not that big of an issue.

Comment: Being in an early game with hardcore players/scripters helps a lot, but is there a new thing one can do to help them?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, I can't click fast enough to kill anything.  Not fast enough to even deploy an item to help.  Things are dying so fast it's just a blur of death animations.

Comment: Wow. Do you even need to buy any armor?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, yeah, at the real high levels they'll hit hard even in the first second or two.  I invest in armor and the auto-fire cannon, and deploy items as I feel like it (ie, if the daily challenge is item related).

Comment: Alternatively, join a running game, but be prepared to respawn until you've bought enough armor.

Comment: `using them so that every level we clear skips a good 5-10 levels easily.` - Please stop using wormholes in the 90s or even lower, because on level multiples of 100, wormholes are 10 times as efficient.

Answer (score 7):

Use the badges you have gotten from the previous game to buy upgrades. Personally i would suggest to buy a mixture of the ones that give 100k gold and those that give 1% of targets money per click. I guess you can also buy a bunch of the Cripple Spawner items to get rid of spawners more quickly.
Use the 100k gold items to get yourself started. Use the 1% per click items on bosses (every 10th level). If you are going to check every so often, don't use up all your 1% items straight away... Save some for higher level bosses.
**Do NOT use high damage abilities on bosses, since other people are going to use the 1% items to click themselves rich.**
Which upgrades to get:
10x Light Armor
10x Heavy Armor
5x Energy Shield (this should give you more then enough health points even for high levels)
10x Auto-fire Cannon
10x Advanced Targeting
10x Farming Equipment
..x AFK Equipment (as many as you can get (10k damage per rank))
??x Boss Loot (own choice)
4x for each Elemental Damage
Don't focus on just the armor or just the auto-fire. upgrade them both approx at the same time. As you may have noticed, no click upgrades. Unless you want to click alot, it is better to upgrade your auto fire so you keep doing damage even though you are not in the game.
Abilities (if you are going to check on the game every so often):
Medics
Tactical Nuke
Cluster Bomb
Napalm
You will have to come back to the game every so often to check up on your money status and see if you can buy some more upgrades.
Also, check the prices for the different categories and go for the cheaper ones first (if you already upgraded to 4x elemental damage for each elemental type but not your auto-fire, you still don't do alot of damage.
If you got alot of money to spend ingame, do it on auto-fire / elemental damage options.

Comment: Save up for the higher tier unless the current one costs less than a tenth as much.

Comment: Reddit commenters say they've reached level 4000. I don't think 5 Energy Shield is enough for that. Also, why not level 5 Elementals? In my screenshots, those gave much cheaper DPS than the weapon upgrades. I guess 10k DPS from tier 5 weapons is to thank. Also, those 1% items (Raining Gold) benefit everyone.

Comment: To reach the top of level 100,000,000, the only way is to stack the Wormhole ability on level multiples of 100, so do as little damage as possible there.